# message when a UITableView is empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a favorites tabBar in my application that is initially empty. I'd like to put a message on the screen when the tableView is empty, something like "you have no favorites saved".

Ideally, I'd like to show a custom graphic in the center of the screen. Would I use the `numberOfRowsInSection` count and if it returns 0, do something? I've trying this but can't make it work.

Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use `numberOfRowsInSection` as that's a method of the `UITableView` datasource. Instead, on the view controller, after you reload the table view data, check for the number of items, and if it's zero, then you can hide the table view and display an image instead.

Comment: pgb is correct, and I voted him up.  When you add functionality to numberOfRowsInSection that is adding a side-effect that is not part of the selectors contract.  Generally, adding side-effects makes your software more difficult to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the login in viewWillAppear. The items u want to display in the favorites tab should be store in an array. Load the array in viewWillAppear check the count, if zero do ur functionality.